# How to deal with reduced UIView area when embedded in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode7, uipageviewcontroller

I was wondering how best to work with content in a view controller when it's embedded in a navigation controller. The setup is:

**UINavigationController -> UIPageViewController -> ViewController(s)**

when `UIPageViewController` is not embedded in `UINavigationController` all the content of each `ViewController` is visible. When it is embedded in `UINavigationController` the content in each ViewController is pushed down (so it doesn't go under the nav bar) so the bottom area of content is lost.

Is there a way to design content in a ViewController in IB when it's going to be pushed down by the navigation bar? How do you know what it will look like if what you see in IB is not what you'll get in the app?

Answer (score 0):

You should use layout constraints to avoid this problems.

Check out [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) tutorial